# Export Mysql Results in Netbeans to csv

Tags: mysql, netbeans, csv

Is there a way to easily export the returned results from Netbean's SQL Editor to a csv file on my local computer?

Answer (score 1):

I simply copied the rows and pasted them into a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

It is recorded in bugzilla. There is no update after 10/2009.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=154740

I just moved over from eclipse and am quite bummed. Trying to use squirrel as I don't want to go back to eclipse for java development. Personal choice mostly.